# Problems with RESTKit, cannot map properly

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

I am learning RESTKit, and I am following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial) tutorial, which is according to previous version of RESTKit, and a lot has changed in v0.20.0, so I am reading about the new version and doing the same task as in tutorial.

Now there is a problem in the mapping, and I have spent many hours on it without success. The error I am getting is:

```
error: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0x758d320 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=<client id>&client_secret=KYHQHRYJ4PYFJYEG1F1IQVLQDM4G1HZ1STB2O1VUVUVQZBGS<client secret>&ll=37.33,-122.03&query=coffee&v=20120602, NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=<client id>&client_secret=<client secret>&ll=37.33,-122.03&query=coffee&v=20120602', which failed to match all (1) response descriptors:
  <RKResponseDescriptor: 0x9566a60 baseURL=https://api.Foursquare.com/v2/ pathPattern=(null) statusCodes=200-299> failed to match: response URL 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=<client id>&client_secret=<client secret>&ll=37.33,-122.03&query=coffee&v=20120602' is not relative to the baseURL 'https://api.Foursquare.com/v2/'., NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded., keyPath=null, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=<client id>&client_secret=<client secret>&ll=37.33,-122.03&query=coffee&v=20120602, NSUnderlyingError=0x758d3a0 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."}
```

Venue.h is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Venue : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;

@end
```

Venue.m is:

```
#import "Venue.h"

@implementation Venue
@synthesize name;

@end
```

And I am doing everything in MasterViewController.m in ViewDidAppear method, which is:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.Foursquare.com/v2"];

    AFHTTPClient * client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

    RKObjectMapping *venueMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Venue class]];
    [venueMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"name" : @"name"
     }];

    RKResponseDescriptor * responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venueMapping
                                                                                        pathPattern:nil
                                                                                            keyPath:@"response.venues"
                                                                                        statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

    NSString *latLon = @"37.33,-122.03";
    NSString *clientID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kCLIENTID];
    NSString *clientSecret = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kCLIENTSECRET];

    NSDictionary *queryParams;
    queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:latLon, @"ll", clientID, @"client_id", clientSecret, @"client_secret", @"coffee", @"query", @"20120602", @"v", nil];
    //NSLog(@"object manager: %@ - %@", objectManager.baseURL, [[objectManager responseDescriptors] objectAtIndex:0]);

    /*
    RKRelationshipMapping* relationShipMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"venues"
                                                                                             toKeyPath:@"venues"
                                                                                           withMapping:venueMapping];
    [venueMapping addPropertyMapping:relationShipMapping]; */
    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"https://api.Foursquare.com/v2/venues/search"
                         parameters:queryParams
                         success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operaton, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
                         {
                             NSLog(@"success: mappings: %@", mappingResult);
                         }
                         failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operaton, NSError * error)
                         {
                             NSLog (@"failure: operation: %@ \n\nerror: %@", operaton, error);
                         }];

}
```

I have checked the response in the browser, and it is ok, but for some reason whatever I did didn't get rid of the error. I am stuck in the first step of mapping, and cannot move forward. All the examples and documents on the subject on the internet are outdated and having no experience with RESTKit's older versions I am not able to figure things out. Please tell what am I doing wrong.

Using xcode 4.5 and building for iOS6.

Response is (checked on browser):

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"response":{"venues":[{"id":"4f482132e4b0f85d07c34cb5","name":"De Anza 3 Coffee Bar","contact":{},"location":{"address":"10500 De Anza Blvd","lat":37.329438,"lng":-122.03083,"distance":96,"postalCode":"95014","city":"Cupertino","state":"CA","country":"United States","cc":"US"},"canonicalUrl":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/v\/de-anza-3-coffee-bar\/4f482132e4b0f85d07c34cb5","categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735","name":"Coffee Shop","pluralName":"Coffee Shops","shortName":"Coffee Shop","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/img\/categories\/food\/coffeeshop_","sizes":[32,44,64,88,256],"name":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"restricted":true,"stats":{"checkinsCount":1,"usersCount":1,"tipCount":0},"likes":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1357121711"},{"id":"40ccea80f964a52019011fe3","name":"Coffee Society","contact":{"phone":"4087258091","formattedPhone":"(408) 725-8091"},"location":{"address":"21265 Stevens Creek Blvd","crossStreet":"at Oaks Shopping Center","lat":37.32330342,"lng":-122.047382,"distance":1709,"postalCode":"95014","city":"Cupertino","state":"CA","country":"United States","cc":"US"},"canonicalUrl":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/v\/coffee-society\/40ccea80f964a52019011fe3","categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735","name":"Coffee Shop","pluralName":"Coffee Shops","shortName":"Coffee Shop","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/foursquare.com\/img\/categories\/food\/coffeeshop_","sizes":[32,44,64,88,256],"name":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"restricted":true,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2536,"usersCount":869,"tipCount":24},"likes":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1357121711"}, .....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I attempted to convert the exact same tutorial to version 0.20 and finally what fixed it for me was making the URL lower case (https://api.Foursquare.com/v2).  Replace that capital 'F' with a lowercase f, so all is lower case.  It appears that RESTKit expects all lower case and is case-sensitive, but I'm new to iOS programming and RESTKit.

Also note:

1. No need for RKRelationshipMapping stuff
2. pathPattern:nil &
   keyPath:@"response.venues"

I believe you have these already, but I wanted to be verbose just in case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never expected this to be the problem, and also thanks for the effort of converting the tutorial to v0.20!

Comment: @Tilo Where can we find your converted tutorial?  It would help quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

For people coming here and don't have the CAPS issue (like me), check out [this github resolution](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1060) post by RestKit's creator. It helped me figure out [my path issues](http://www.readncode.com/blog/2013/04/28/restkit-0-dot-20-no-response-descriptors-match-the-response-loaded/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried keyPath as simply "venues" instead of "response.venues"?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've used a baseURL with your custom HTTP Client, try using just the path extension:

```
 [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/venues/search"
                     parameters:queryParams
                     success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operaton, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
                     {
                         NSLog(@"success: mappings: %@", mappingResult);
                     }
                     failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation * operaton, NSError * error)
                     {
                         NSLog (@"failure: operation: %@ \n\nerror: %@", operaton, error);
                     }];
```

And also add the path in your response descriptor:

```
RKResponseDescriptor * responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:venueMapping
                                                                                    pathPattern:@"/venues/search"
                                                                                        keyPath:@"venues"
                                                                                    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Comment: Tried this as well, no success. I have built this and few other examples working properly with older version of RestKit (0.10.x) but for some reason I am not able to get things working with the latest version.